# Django-Ajax: submitting forms with AJAX that inludes a file field, giving me 500 error: Object of type 'FieldFile' is not JSON serializable

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-forms

so, as the title states, im trying to upload a form using ajax, and the form , along with other fields, includes a FileField to upload an image. however,  when I make the request, ajax cannot return a response to me because 'FILEFIELD is not JSON serializable'. so, here is the code:

model:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    job_title= models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    years_experience = models.IntegerField()

    PRODUCTION = 'PR'
    RESEARCH_DEVELOPMENT= 'R&D'
    PURCHASING = 'PU'
    MARKETING = 'MA'
    HUMAN_RESOURCES = 'HR'
    ACCOUTING = 'AC'
    DEPARTMENT_CHOICES = (
        (PRODUCTION, 'Production'),
        (RESEARCH_DEVELOPMENT, 'Research and Development'),
        (PURCHASING, 'Purchasing'),
        (MARKETING, 'Marketing'),
        (HUMAN_RESOURCES, 'Human Resource Management'),
        (ACCOUTING, 'Accounting')
    )

    department = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                      choices=DEPARTMENT_CHOICES,
                                      default=PRODUCTION)

    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is the associated modelForm:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Employee

class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('name', 'job_title', 'years_experience', 'department', 'image',)
        labels = {
            'years_experience': ('years of experience')
        }
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'id': 'employee-name', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Employee name...'}
            ),
            'job_title': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'id': 'employee-job-title', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Employee title'}
            ),
            'years_experience': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'id': 'employee-years-experience', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Years of experience...'}
            ),
            'department': forms.Select(
                attrs={'id': 'employee-department', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'department...'}
            ),
            'image': forms.FileInput(
                attrs={'id': 'employee-image', 'required': True}
            ),
        }
```

here is the view to handle subbmitting the form:

def create_post(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    employee_name = request.POST.get('name')
    employee_title = request.POST.get('job_title')
    employee_experience = request.POST.get('years_experience')
    employee_department = request.POST.get('department')
    employee_image = request.FILES.get('image')

    # response_data = {}

    employee = Employee(name=employee_name, job_title=employee_title, years_experience=employee_experience, department=employee_department, image=employee_image)
    employee.save()

    return JsonResponse(model_to_dict(employee))


else:
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

here is the javascript/ajax code:

```
$(function() {
$('#employee-form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!");
    create_employee();
  })
function create_employee() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "/employees/create_post/", // target the endpoint
      type: "POST",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(json) {
        ('#employee-form').trigger("reset");
        console.log(json);
        console.log('success');
      },
  error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){
        $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+" <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
      }
    });
};
```

I have tried several solutions, such as FormData, as well as a jquery Ajax Form Plugin, both of which didn't get me anywhere. This is part of a coding challenge I must complete, so any prompt answers would be really appreciated! love you all

Answer (score 0):

You can't set send the file data in JSON send it as form data.

```
var form = $("#Form");
var formData = new FormData(form[0]);

if ($(form).valid()) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(form).prop("action"),
        //dataType: 'json', //not sure but works for me without this
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        error   : ErrorHandler,
        success : successHandler
    });
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me, but this seems to be the correct answer, according to several other answers ive looked at. still getting the same error! thanks anyways